# Calling a synchronous method from an async method in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, async-await

I am working on a C# asp.net web API project. I am new to asynchronous programming.

In my `GetOrderNumberAsync` async method, I have to call a legacy synchronous method as shown in line #20. It's a database call to update data in a SQL server table.

I am thinking of rewriting it using `Task.Run()` as shown in line #21.

Will it cause a deadlock? I couldn't find a definite answer after my extensive Google search.

```
1 [HttpPost]
2 [Route("FreshOrder")]
3 public async Task FreshOrder([FromBody] JObject jsonResult)
4 {
5    string resourceURL = JObject.Parse(jsonResult.ToString())["resource_url"].ToString();
6    await GetOrderNumberAsync(resourceURL);
7 }

8 private async Task GetOrderNumberAsync(string queryURL)
9 {
10  int rowsAffected;
11    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
12    {

13  string resp = await client.GetStringAsync(queryURL);

14  var jObj = JObject.Parse(resp);
15  JArray orders = (JArray)jObj["orders"];

16  foreach (JToken order in orders)
17  {
18         string customerId = (string)order["customerId"];
19     string customerNumber = (string)order["customerNumber"];
20     rowsAffected = order.UpdateData(customerId, customerNumber);
21     //rowsAffected = await Task.Run(() => 
       //  order.UpdateData(customerId, 
       //customerNumber));
22  }       
23 }
```

Comment: I would assume that `UpdateData` is an I/O heavy operation based on its name. Using `Task.Run` for an I/O bound operation is not a good idea, since it was [designed for CPU bound operations](https://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/#:~:text=The%20main%20purpose%20of%20Task,IO%2Dbound%20work%20in%20Task.). In other words it will try to use a dedicated thread to issue an I/O operation.

Comment: It's a database call to update data in a SQL server table.

Comment: So, that's a synchronous I/O operation. You don't get any benefit (according to my understanding) to put it into a `Task.Run`. Simply just call it without `Task.Run`. You are already gaining some advantage of the asynchronous I/O  at the httpClient call.

Comment: Not tightly related to the question but please read [this article](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) about `HttpClient` and `using` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `Task.Run`, but not for the reason you think.

`Task.Run` would not cause a deadlock. The [common deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) occurs when some code blocks on asynchronous code while within a single-threaded context. In this case, the code is running synchronous code on a background thread (`Task.Run`) and then `await`ing it. This would not deadlock.

However, you still shouldn't use `Task.Run`. This is because ASP.NET is *already* running this request on a thread pool thread. `await Task.Run` will schedule part of the request (the DB update) onto a *different* thread pool thread and then "yield" back to the ASP.NET runtime, returning the current thread pool thread back to the thread pool. So, on ASP.NET, `Task.Run` just causes a thread switch while providing no benefit. [Quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet):

> You can kick off some background work by awaiting Task.Run, but there’s no point in doing so. In fact, that will actually hurt your scalability by interfering with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics... As a general rule, don’t queue work to the thread pool on ASP.NET.

If the method was asynchronous *already* (or if there was an asynchronous version of the method), then your code should certainly use that with `await`. But since the code is synchronous, just make it a direct synchronous call (no `Task.Run`) until you are ready to make the database methods asynchronous.